# Is there a built-in or more Pythonic way to try to parse a string to an integer

Tags: python, parsing, integer

I had to write the following function to fail gracefully when trying to parse a string to an integer. I would imagine Python has something built in to do this, but I can't find it. If not, is there a more Pythonic way of doing this that doesn't require a separate function?

```
def try_parse_int(s, base=10, val=None):
  try:
    return int(s, base)
  except ValueError:
    return val
```

The solution I ended up using was a modification of @sharjeel's answer. The following is functionally identical, but, I think, more readable.

```
def ignore_exception(exception=Exception, default_val=None):
  """Returns a decorator that ignores an exception raised by the function it
  decorates.

  Using it as a decorator:

    @ignore_exception(ValueError)
    def my_function():
      pass

  Using it as a function wrapper:

    int_try_parse = ignore_exception(ValueError)(int)
  """
  def decorator(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
      try:
        return function(*args, **kwargs)
      except exception:
        return default_val
    return wrapper
  return decorator
```

Comment: @Paul Hildebrandt: Not only fine, but the most Pythonic.

Comment: I think your example is additionally valuable for demonstrating a practical use for decorators.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This is a pretty regular scenario so I've written an "ignore_exception" decorator that works for all kinds of functions which throw exceptions instead of failing gracefully:

```
def ignore_exception(IgnoreException=Exception,DefaultVal=None):
    """ Decorator for ignoring exception from a function
    e.g.   @ignore_exception(DivideByZero)
    e.g.2. ignore_exception(DivideByZero)(Divide)(2/0)
    """
    def dec(function):
        def _dec(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return function(*args, **kwargs)
            except IgnoreException:
                return DefaultVal
        return _dec
    return dec
```

Usage in your case:

```
sint = ignore_exception(ValueError)(int)
print sint("Hello World") # prints none
print sint("1340") # prints 1340
```

Comment: While this is clever, and possibly even useful if you are going to decorate a lot of functions with it, it does not answer the question as expressed in the subject line.  (The answer to the subject line is:  there is no built-in, and the OP's original code is already the most Pythonic way.)

Comment: Yeah, I agree with John but I voted you up for bring the cleaver.

Comment: This answer is about as Pythonic as the COBOL ALTER verb.

Answer (score 49):

```
def intTryParse(value):
    try:
        return int(value), True
    except ValueError:
        return value, False
```

Answer (score 49):

Actually there is a "built-in", **single line solution** that doesn't require introducing a helper function:

```py
>>> s = "123"
>>> i = int(s) if s.isdecimal() else None
>>> print(i)
123

>>> s = "abc"
>>> i = int(s) if s.isdecimal() else None
>>> print(i)
None

>>> s = ""
>>> i = int(s) if s.isdecimal() else None
>>> print(i)
None

>>> s = "1a"
>>> i = int(s) if s.isdecimal() else None
>>> print(i)
None
```

In case you need to support negative numbers, too, the following extension considers one (or more) leading dashes/minus as the algebraic sign for negative numbers:

```py
>>> s = "-123"
>>> i = int(s) if s.split("-", 1)[-1].isdecimal() else None
>>> print(i)
-123
```

See also:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdecimal
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: Unfortunately, this breaks `int("\u00B2") if "\u00B2".isdigit() else None`

Comment: `isdecimal()` works better, e.g., `"\u00B2".isdecimal()` is `False`

Comment: This doesn't work on negative numbers. `"-123".isdigit() # False`.

Comment: .isdecimal() also doesn't handle negative numbers. `"-123".isdecimal()` is `False`

Comment: @mattmc3 and Nils great feedback -- just added an extension to my answer which keeps the expression simple enough while still supporting negative numbers.

Answer (score 26):

That's the pythonic way. In python, it's customary to use EAFP style - Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission.
That means you'd try first, and then clean up the mess if necessary.

Comment: @abyx:  I like the first two sentences.  I don't like the third.  When you say "then once you're sure perform the action" it sounds like you are describing LBYL, even though the first part of that sentence is more-or-less correct for EAFP.  I would say "EAFP = just try, and clean up the mess if it fails".

Answer (score 16):

I would go for:

```
def parse_int(s, base=10, val=None):
 if s.isdigit():
  return int(s, base)
 else:
  return val
```

But it's more or less the same thing.

Comment: Didn't know about str.isdigit. That could be useful. Thanks.

Comment: Please, take into account abyx answer. He's right and you should use your code, instead of mine.

Comment: Not only is the EAFP style more appropriate and more Pythonic in this situation, it handles negative integers while isdigit doesn't.

Comment: EAFP is always better if it is possible. I wanted to suggest this, but I realized the case with unicode numeric characters is also missing, so you have to use unicode.isnumeric and it's no longer symmteric for str/unicode. And so on.

Comment: And the hexadecimal case is also missing, now you need .ishexdigit(). No, the best way to find out if you can do XX? Try doing XX! Which is exactly what the original code says :-)

Answer (score 7):

No, it is already perfect. The `val` parameter could be better named default, though.

Documented in the official docs simply as [int(x) -- x converted to integer](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex)

Comment: Thanks. It's unfortunate that there's no built-in means of parsing an integer that doesn't raise an exception.

Comment: @Christopher: Why is it unfortunate?  How is try-except not built-in?

Comment: @Christopher: This is how it is Python's "culture" and I am sure you will find the same pattern in other places

Comment: @Roger, it's unfortunate because using try-except adds 3 lines of code everywhere I want silent failure. dict's get method embodies a similar spirit in that it does not raise an exception. And rather than write my own method to handle this situation, this seems like something that should be built in to the Python language. For example, the hypothetical method call int.try_parse('not integer', None) would just return None instead of raising ValueError. In asking this question, I was hoping someone would tell me that something similar does, in fact, exist.

Comment: "And rather than write my own method to handle this situation, this seems like something that should be built in to the Python language"  Sorry, I don't agree with this.  I've Been coding in Python for 6 years.  Never needed this construct.  You can write a function because -- clearly -- you need this.

Answer (score 2):

int() is the built-in and pythonic way, just like you have there.

It's usually easier and more common to use it directly though:

```
def show_square(user_input):
  """Example of using int()."""
  try:
    num = int(user_input, 10)
  except ValueError:
    print "Error" # handle not-an-integer case
    # or you may just want to raise an exception here
    # or re-raise the ValueError
  else:
    print "Times two is", num * 2

def another_example(user_input):
  try:
    num = int(user_input, 10)
  except ValueError:
    num = default
  print "Times two is", num * 2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
myList = ['12', '13', '5', 'hope', 'despair', '69','0', '1.2']

myInts = [int(x) for x in myList if x.isdigit()]
```

Comment: This doesn't work for negative numbers, e.g. "-1"

Answer (score 1):

This could be another alternative for parsing string to int

```
while True:
try:
    n = input("Please enter an integer: ")
    n = int(n)
    break
except ValueError:
    print("No valid integer! Please try again ...")
print("Great, you successfully entered an integer!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the circumstances, the following might fit the needs of some readers: leveraging short-circuiting, you can obtain either `False` or an actual integer, and you can check for its type.

```
pos = s.strip().lstrip("-")
number = pos.isdecimal() and pos.isdigit() and int(s)
if number is not False:
```

Just remember that `False == 0` yields `True`. So, don't straight up compare it to an integer without first checking that is not `False`. Another option would be as follows,

```
pos = s.strip().lstrip("-") 
if pos.isdecimal() and pos.isdigit() and (int(s) == test_number):
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a smart flexible integer casting algorithm.

Here is a similar attempt in Python.

```
def parseInt(txt: str) -> int:
    """
    PHP like integer parsing.

    Args:
        txt (str): string to parse.

    Returns:
        int: found integer.

    :Example:
    >>> parseInt("")
    0
    >>> parseInt("-")
    0
    >>> parseInt("-a")
    0
    >>> parseInt("-456as")
    -456
    >>> parseInt("123456z654")
    123456
    """
    if not len(txt):
        return 0
    result = ""
    if txt[0] == "-":
        result = "-0"
        txt = txt[1:]
    for char in txt:
        if char.isdigit():
            result += char
        else:
            break
    else:
        return 0
    return int(result)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
def parseint(string):
    result = '0'
    for x in string:
        if x.isdigit():
        result+=x
    else:
        return int(result)
    return int(result)
```

Comment: Bad idea. It produces bogus results. Assuming the indentation on line 5 is fixed, parseint('-3') => 3; parseint('2by2') => 22; etc. Note also that the first return is always executed since there's no break in the loop.