# Classify if a number is an int or float with input function. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: python, input, integer

I guys, im a noob on the programming world and im putting my best to learn Python.

Im stuck with this problem right now:

"Make an algorithm that verifies if a certain value is an integer."

Now the problem is that the INPUT function returns the type in string. If I cast the variable to FLOAT it stops me from reading the integer numbers.

What should i do?

```
val1 = float(input("enter value")
if type (val1)== int:
print("value is integer")
else:
print("value is NOT integer")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have a look at this question, which explains how to convert a string into an integer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262333/is-there-a-built-in-or-more-pythonic-way-to-try-to-parse-a-string-to-an-integer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse a string to a float or int in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to covert the string input into an integer or float:

```
k = input("enter value:")
try:
    k = int(k)
    # it is an integer
except ValueError:
    try:
        k = float(k)
    except ValueError:
        print("Neither int nor float")
    else:
        print(k, "is a float")
else:
    print(k, "is an integer")
```

Output:

```
enter value:44.4
44.4 is a float

enter value:hallo 
Neither int nor float

enter value:44
44 is an integer
```

Doku:

- [Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)
- [Exception handling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `try` and `except` for this (you can give it a look at [Errors and Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html). Try turning the `input` into an `int`, and write the corresponding print statements depending on the result:

```
val1 = input("enter value")
try:
    int(val1)
    print("value is integer")
except:
    print("value is NOT integer")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want also input like `'3.0'` to be recognized as integers (so all whole numbers, instead of all values of type `int`), just calling `int` on it is not enough, since `int` cannot parse that string.

Another way to determine if a value is a whole number is to see if there is a rest if divided by one, so you can use the modulo operator `%`:

```
val1 = float(input("enter value"))
if val1 % 1 == 0:
    print("value is integer")
else:
    print("value is NOT integer")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t want casting and error handling. You can use ast.literal_eval that transform string to Python objects and isinstance, which comes with Python, to solve your issue.

```
from ast import literal_eval


in_val = input('Enter value: ')

# get literal value

l_val = literal_eval(in_val)

# check if it is int
if isinstance(l_val,int):
    print('It is integer')
elif isinstance(l_val,float):
    print('It is a float')
elif isinstance(l_val,str):
    print('It is a string')

else:
    print('Not int,float or string')# could be list, dict etc ;)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if val1.count('.') == 0:
   print("value is NOT integer")
else:
   print("value is integer")
```

Comment: if you get a string input like "3.14" and its contains a dot then its a float.

Comment: This will fail with input like `'3e4'`, which is a `float` (and `int` cannot parse it).