# How to return false on casting value

Tags: python

I want to return value without any error while casting string to integer.

**For example**, if I have a string *"Hello World"*, it will return to false instead of error when I would like to use casting process.

This is **error statement** when I tried to casting string into int:

> "ValueError: invalid literal for `int()` with base 10: 'From fairest creatures we desire increase,'"

`string = int`('From fairest creatures we desire increase,')

Comment: Share your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a built-in or more Pythonic way to try to parse a string to an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262333/is-there-a-built-in-or-more-pythonic-way-to-try-to-parse-a-string-to-an-integer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a function for it.

```
def to_int(string):
    try:
        return int(string)
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

And call it like this:

```
>>> to_int("Hello World")
False
>>> to_int("10")
10
```

You could also add an optional Default value if you want to be more flexible

```
def to_int(string, default = False):
    try:
        return int(string)
    except ValueError:
        return default
```

Answer (score 0):

Strictly what you wanted but please **read further**:

```
def to_int(string):
    try:
        return int(string)
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

But in my opinion it should return `None` instead of `False`. Why? Booleans can be **treated as ints** [sic]:

```
>>> True + True
2
>>> False + False
2
>>> True < 2
True
>>> False < 2
True
>>> True + 1
2
>>> False + 1
1
```

etc.

So I recommend using:

```
def to_int(string):
    try:
        return int(string)
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

It will help you avoid some strange bugs, not mentioning that it simply sounds better.

Return `False` when there's a complimentary case when `True` can be returned as well. If not, return a valid value or `None` when it's not possible.

Answer (score -2):

```
def fun(str):
    if str.isdigit():
        return int(str)
    else:
        return False
```

this function will return int value if whole string is digit otherwise it will return False

Comment: Although this will work it is not very pythotic, because it is against the [EAFP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11360880/8411228) rule

Comment: No no no no no. Never Look Before You Leap. If you try this with `'²'` it'll crash.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: nice one, didn't know `'²'` is considered a digit. Isn't it weird that it's a digit but it cannot build a valid number?