# Type Conversion to Integer in Python using int()

Tags: python-3.x, type-conversion

Why does

```
x = int(34.43)
y = int('72')
z = float('22.43')
```

give x = 34, y= 72 and z = 22.43

but

```
x = int('10.8')
```

result in an error, and not x = 10

Does it have something to do with how float values are stored in memory? Any detailed explanations as to why this happens are most welcome (not how to resolve this issue). Thanks in advance

Comment: "Strings with decimals cannot be immediately cast to an integer because integers do not have decimals, but floats do handle decimals and can be cast to integers." [Source](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-convert-a-string-with-decimals-to-an-integer-in-python)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262333/is-there-a-built-in-or-more-pythonic-way-to-try-to-parse-a-string-to-an-integer

Comment: install the try parse library https://pypi.org/project/try-parse/ then check if the string can be parse as an integer

Comment: you can't convert a float in a string to an int base 10 directly.  You can use the type to determine if the string is int or float then cast accordingly.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int

Comment: x=round(float("10.8"),0)
print(x)  if your not downcasting otherwise x=int(float("10.8")) https://www.java67.com/2015/10/how-to-convert-float-to-int-in-java-example.html