# How to multiply the elements of a list of type str, in which there are only digits, by a number of type int?

Tags: python

incoming_list = ['5', 6 , 3.5 , '6', 'g', '9']

Need a result: ['10', 6 , 3.5 , '12', 'g', '18']

The essence of the task as a whole: It is necessary to display another list from one list while observing certain conditions. And all this needs to be done through the list generator using the if else constructs. For example, the conditions for the list to include numbers are float, int paired, int unpaired to a power, and this condition is to multiply numbers of type str by a number. I have fulfilled all the conditions except the last one. Try except doesn't work. It is necessary only through if else. Stuck on this

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension here:

```py
incoming_list = ['5', 6 , 3.5 , '6', 'g', '9']
output = [str(int(x) * 2) if isinstance(x, str) and x.isnumeric() else x for x in incoming_list]
print(output)  # ['10', 6, 3.5, '12', 'g', '18']
```

In case the list value be a numeric integer string, we return a string which is twice the original value.  Otherwise, we just return the same original value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use just loop through the array and use `type` to check if the value is a string:

```
type(your_str) == str
```

And if it is, then use `isdigit` to check if the value can be parsed to an integer:

```
i = int(s) if s.isdigit() else None
```

(taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59359048/3730626), go there for more examples). If `i` is None, then its a letter and should not be considered. If it is a number, then assign it back to the array. This solution only uses `if else`, and no `try catch`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use isinstance (python3) to check the data type.

```
>>> [ x if isinstance(x,float) or isinstance(x,int) else str(int(x)*2) if x.isdigit() else x for x in ['5', 6 , 3.5 , '6', 'g', '9']]
['10', 6, 3.5, '12', 'g', '18']
```